# c++ zero out memory of a function

Tags: c++, memory, zero

I have a little idea related to reflective dll injection. If you do not know, what reflective dll injection is, you can check it out here: https://github.com/stephenfewer/ReflectiveDLLInjection

What is basically does, is load the dll to memory and then inject the memory into the target process - at least that's what happens afaik. I might be wrong, but that does not matter atm.

**Task**

1. Find the memory address of a given function
2. Find the size of the given function
3. Zero out the memory using `SecureZeroMemory()`

**Code**

```
#include "ReflectiveLoader.h"

extern HINSTANCE hAppInstance;

void Function1() { MessageBoxA(NULL, "Function 1 called!", "Test", MB_OK); }
void Function2() { MessageBoxA(NULL, "Function 2 called!", "Test", MB_OK); }
void Function3() { MessageBoxA(NULL, "Function 3 called!", "Test", MB_OK); }

void GetMemoryInformation()
{
    void(*p_Func1)() = &Function1;
    void(*p_Func2)() = &Function2;
    void(*p_Func3)() = &Function3;

    char buffer[300];
    sprintf(buffer, "Function1 - Address: %p | Size: %zu \nFunction2 - Address: %p | Size: %zu \nFunction3 - Address: %p | Size: %zu", 
        p_Func1, sizeof(p_Func1),
        p_Func2, sizeof(p_Func2),
        p_Func3, sizeof(p_Func3)
        );

    MessageBoxA(NULL, buffer, "Memory information", MB_OK);
}

void ZeroMemoryFunctions()
{
    void(*p_Func2)() = &Function2;
    void(*p_Func3)() = &Function3;

    SecureZeroMemory(p_Func2, sizeof(p_Func2));
    SecureZeroMemory(p_Func3, sizeof(p_Func3));
}

DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID PARAMS)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Main thread initialized!", "Entry", MB_OK);
    for (;;)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x31) & 0x8000) Function1(); // key 1
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x32) & 0x8000) Function2(); // key 2
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x33) & 0x8000) Function3(); // key 3

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000) GetMemoryInformation();
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000) ZeroMemoryFunctions();

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000) MessageBoxA(NULL, "Main thread closed!", "Exit", MB_OK), ExitThread(0);

        Sleep(100);
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    BOOL bReturnValue = TRUE;
    switch( dwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_QUERY_HMODULE:
            if( lpReserved != NULL )
                *(HMODULE *)lpReserved = hAppInstance;
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hAppInstance = hinstDLL;

            MessageBoxA( NULL, "Reflective Dll injected!", "Injected", MB_OK );
            CreateThread(0, 0, &MainThread, 0, 0, 0);

            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return bReturnValue;
}
```

**What it does?**

- Key 1 to 3, calls the specified function that displays a simple message box
- Up arrow displays a message box with a function address and size to each function
- Down arrow zeros out functions `Function2()` and `Function3()`
- Escape exits the main thread normally

**Problems**

I'm very new to memory related coding, so I'm pretty sure I did something wrong.

I believe I'm getting the size of the function in a wrong way and instead I'm getting the size of the pointer to the function, am I correct?

Secondarily, if I call `ZeroMemoryFunctions()` and press key 1, it works. When I press key 2 or 3, the target process crashes, cause the functions memory got zeroed out. This means, that `SecureZeroMemory()` worked, correct? But because of the wrong size of the block to fill with zeroes, it was only partially zeroed, I believe.

Comment: So is this just a really convoluted attempt to emulate *NIX shared objects on windows, by writing your own ld.so equivalent? Oh, and can't you just inspect the sizes, and the possibly-partially-zeroed memory, in a debugger?

Comment: `sizeof(p_Func1)` is definitely the size of the pointer, not the function pointed to. I don't know a reliable way to get the code size. The crash itself might be because you don't have enough permissions to write to code space. All kinds of anti-virus features might stop you from doing that.

Comment: The purpose of this is, that I could select random functions out of x functions on injection that will be used in the code. I want to zero out the rest of the functions, that were not selected by random. I'm very very new to coding in c like language, specially related to memory actions, so I have no idea what you're talking about @Useless, I'm apologize. I'm not sure I even know how to use the debugger to do it, but it should be logical that only 8 bytes get zeroed out, since that's the size of the pointer. The problem at hand, is getting the size of the function to zero out.

Comment: @PriitJõe - So you're specifically asking about Task.2?

Comment: I still don't really understand what you achieve by zeroing out the function code - it doesn't release the memory, you can't call it, and if you don't call it anyway why does it matter if the memory is zeroed?

Comment: The memory can be dumped and traces of the functions found, if you get a random function that essentially does the same, but in a different manner - you'll end up with an unique dump of the memory every time. Please correct me, if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

- You do not change the memory protection (it could / should be read + execute), you'd need to make it writable with for example `VirtualProtect`
- It is not an easy task to get the function size. Functions can / will be broken up in multiple pieces by the compiler, and some might get inlined etc.

**Possible solutions**

Ordered from easiest to hardest (to implement correctly).

- Move your functions to a seperate section in the PE file. (using [`alloc_text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw8ty6zf.aspx) in msvc for example)
- Insert helper stubs after the function so you can use those as 'size' marker. (see note 1).
- Determine the size of the function at runtime using a disassembler like [`capstone`](http://www.capstone-engine.org/)

*Note 1:*

Using a construction like this:

```
void function_to_erase()
{
    // your logic here
}

void function_to_erase_helper()
{
    // empty
}
```

You can determine the size of `function_to_erase` by subtracting the address of the helper from your function, ***if, and only if you force the compiler to not reorder those functions.*** (`Project properties->Linker->Optimization->Function Order`)

Comment: This actually makes sense, in some way at least, but I'm going to have to do some more searching, to fully understand all of this, since I'm very new to C like languages, like I've mentioned multiple times in this question already. How do you suggest I erase that function after getting the size? Would SecureZeroMemory() do the trick, like I did in the op or is there another way to actually erase that part from the memory? Zeroing out, simply replaces the bytes with zeroes, but that leaves a trace (of zeroes), if I'm correct.

Comment: Well of course setting something to zero leaves `a trace of zeroes`. What would you expect, that setting it to zero burns a hole in your physical ram, as to make sure it will never be found?

Comment: Funny, lol. Sorry for a dumb question. I was thinking of maybe filtering out the functions to erase in the injector itself, once they get loaded to the memory, so they wouldn't get injected to the target process in the first place.

Comment: Does "Function Order" require me to make a file that lists the exact order of functions or can I make it use the order that they're specified in the source automatically somehow? Also, I couldn't find an example file for how to specify the functions in which order they must be. @MarkJansen

Comment: For all those purposes is the separate section per function (or function group) the easiest. You can enumerate sections in a PE file fairly easy. (In fact, the code that injects into the other process should already do this to apply the correct memory protection flags, so you should be able to modify that to only selectively map the needed sections into memory).